# Using Swagger how to create dynamic json object in body

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I need the swagger editor to have the functionality to change the model in the body and the user should be able to enter the value manually to test the API. The following sample shows two body structure with change in body model structure.Swagger should be made compatible for this change depending on "type" value.

body:
{
"type":"1",
"location":{ "latitude": "4556465.555",
             "longitude": "56622225.55" 
       }
}

{
"type":"2",
"imageUrl" :"http://www.example.com/sample.jpg"
}

Comment: To clarify - you want to associate 2 different bodies with a single Swagger endpoint? Please post the whole Swagger json for that API.

Comment: @Charlie Yes need to have a swagger which can switch to any body structure type as required. Sorry the swagger json is big.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger doesn't let you have more than 1 response schema per API+Status Code so you would need to consider a different approach.

See: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/270